# Top 5 values in a particular row of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 165 columns where I have different values.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
skill1   skill2     slkill3       skill4
1     1     0        54             20
2     0     23       9              2
```

I want to find the top 3 values for a particular row. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option

```
lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(x) sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:3])
#$`1`
#[1] 54 20  1
#
#$`2`
#[1] 23  9  2
```

The return object is a `list` with the top 3 numbers for every row.

Or using `apply`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:3])
#      1  2
#[1,] 54 23
#[2,] 20  9
#[3,]  1  2
```

Here the top 3 numbers are given in every column; column 1 for row 1 of `df` and so on.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text = "   skill1   skill2     slkill3       skill4
1     1     0        54             20
2     0     23       9              2
", header = T)
```

Comment: `apply` is usually slow, out of curiosity what is an alternative to `apply`, that is where you can supply 1 or 2 to mean row or column?

Comment: @NelsonGon *"`apply` is usually slow"* I'm not sure about that. Slow in comparison to what? `tidyverse` solutions are perhaps more elegant but not necessarily faster.

Comment: It's not necessary slower but it coerces to a matrix prior to applying the function. So if you want it to return the result as in 'input' structure, then you will have to convert back to data frame **and** transpose (which is a very expensive operation)

Comment: @Sotos True. Based on OPs sample data it might make sense to work with a `matrix` right from the start (instead of a `data.frame`). Depending on what OP intends to do with the output, there might not be a need to convert to a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most elegant but it might help:

```
tidyr::gather(sort(iris[9,],decreasing = T)[,2:3])#returns top two in row 9
```

Using data from the above answer:

```
tidyr::gather(sort(df[2,],decreasing = T)[,1:3])
df <- read.table(text = "   skill1   skill2     slkill3       skill4
1     1     0        54             20
                 2     0     23       9              2
                 ", header = T)

      key value
1  skill2    23
2 slkill3     9
3  skill4     2
```

Comment: thank you for your reply , but I need a result for a particular row. how to do that?

Comment: I have a feeling you want for a particular column but anyways, you can change 9 to whichever row you want.

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
df %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
 gather(var, val) %>%
 arrange(desc(val)) %>%
 top_n(3)

      var val
1 slkill3  54
2  skill4  20
3  skill1   1
```

With `row_number()` in `filter()` you specify the row number, then transform the data from wide to long, arrange it according values and select the top three greatest values.

Or:

```
df %>%
 filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
 gather(var, val) %>%
 mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(val))) %>%
 filter(rank %in% c(1:3)) %>%
 select(-rank)
```

With `row_number()` in `filter()` you specify the row number, then transform the data from wide to long, creating a ranking variable and then filtering out the cases that are not in top three greatest values.